# Where can I find the Swagger documentation (JSON doc) for the IBM Cloud IAM Identity Services API

Tags: api, swagger, ibm-cloud

Our team is using several IBM Cloud API's in our project. One of them is the IBM Cloud IAM Identity Services API. I am aware that we can use the REST API (using the [IAM Identity Services API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api)) to make calls to our cloud service account.

I would like to know if anyone is aware of where/how to find the actual swagger documentation (the JSON doc) from which this API documentation appears to be generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Swagger or OpenAPI definition by clicking on the three-dot menu on the upper right. That download option should be present for all the [IBM Cloud API documents](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs).

[image: download the API definition]

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, @data_henrik. Very helpful.